Problem using Development Build on Expo Go
This is a beginner issue, I just started working with Expo and this is all new to me. The problem I'm having is being unable to run my app using the Development Build. What I'm trying to do is use a package that is not compatible to Expo (https://www.npmjs.com/package/@config-plugins/react-native-ble-plx), and following the tutorial (https://docs.expo.dev/workflow/customizing/) I read that I need to run the app using the Development Build, which I'm having problems to do it.
The attached picture is what appears on my app.
I followed the tutorial (https://docs.expo.dev/develop/development-builds/use-development-builds/), I did everything without jumping a step, and I'm having the error shown in the attached picture. I checked both versions (on mobile Expo Go app) and on my build and they match (version 51). I tried following the tutorials more than once because I was afraid of user error, I deleted everything and started from zero, and I'm having the issue every time. I'm out of ideas on what to do.

Expo Go and Development build are two things that won't work with the other. Development build is to use the native features on your phone such as Bluetooth, Location, Wifi, etc. Expo Go is supposed to be a simulator of sorts that will build with basic stuff for you.
Expo Go will not work with a Development build. You need to run it on a physical device using
npx expo run:android --device

or on an iOS device with:
npx expo run:ios --device

